# Type mismatch. Required: Nothing Found: Callback<*>

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

In my android project:

```
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback

    fun getAdvertising(callback: Callback<List<Advertising>>) {
        val call = tangoRestClient.advertising
        executeAsync(call, callback)
    }

    private fun executeAsync(call: Call<*>, callback: Callback<*>) {
        call.enqueue(callback)  // compile error
    }
```

But I get compile error:

```
> Task :app:generateDebugSources
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug

> Task :transport:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
e: \TransportService.kt: (127, 14): Out-projected type 'Call<*>' prohibits the use of 'public abstract fun enqueue(p0: Callback<T!>!): Unit defined in retrofit2.Call'

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, the type parameter of `Call` and `Callback` should be the same. You have to write your `executeAsync` function for example like this:

```
private fun <T> executeAsync(call: Call<T>, callback: Callback<T>) {
    call.enqueue(callback)  // no compile error
}
```

It will guarantee that type parameters are the same

Comment: "fun <T>" , why I must add this after "fun". Why not work only this: "private fun executeAsync(call: Call<T>, callback: Callback<T>) {... "  ?

Comment: it's a syntax of type parameters in Kotlin. First, you have to declare a type parameter(after `fun` and before function name) and then use it(in the arguments or return value)